# What is the probability of rolling at least one $6$ in $12$ rolls of a dice?

Tags: probability, dice

> What is the probability of rolling at least one $6$ in $12$ rolls of a dice?

This is a question in my Mathematics textbook. 
The answer is $$1 - \left(\frac56\right)^{12} = 0.89$$

I do not understand how or why this method is used and why the answer is not $\frac16$, because if you roll the same dice $12$ times, does that not mean that the events are independent and that every roll has the probability of $1$ in $6$?

Comment: Hint: the event of rolling at least one six is the complement of the event of rolling no sixes in twelve straight rolls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the events are independent, and every roll has a chance of $\frac{1}{6}$ to be a $6$.  But that does not mean that getting a $6$ in $12$ rolls is also $\frac{1}{6}$.

Basically you are saying that it doesn't matter whether I roll the die $1$ time or a billion times, the probability of getting a $6$ is always $\frac{1}{6}$.  But if you think about it, not getting a $6$ in $1$ roll is quite plausible, but not getting a $6$ in a billion rolls is outrageously unlikely. So, this should tell you *that* there is something wrong in your thinking about this.

OK, but *what* exactly is going wrong? Well, not getting a $6$ in 12 rolls means *more* events need to take place than just not getting a $6$ in 1 roll, and the more events need to take place, the less likely it becomes for *all* those events to take place, even if the probability for *each* of those events is still the same. So that is possibly where your confusion lies: you didn't distinguish between the probability of *all* of those events to take place and the probability of *each* of those events to take place.

Finally, having hopefully cleared up your confusion, let's explain the formula. Well, as I said, in order to *not* get any $6$ in $12$ rolls, $12$ events need to happen: $12$ times you need to *not* roll a $6$, and *each* of those individual events has a probability of $\frac{5}{6}$. So that means that there is a $(\frac{5}{6})^{12}$ probabiity for the overall even of not getting a $6$ at all to take place. Meaning that the chance of getting at least one $6$ is $1-(\frac{5}{6})^{12}$.

Comment: That clears things up. Thank you, but could you explain the formula: 1−(5/6)^12=0.89 as well?

Comment: @badProgrammer Will do ... Hang on a sec ...

Comment: @badProgrammer OK, added that to my answer