# Charting the probability of die values equal to or greater than a variable with N dice

Tags: probability, dice

Math experts, I need your help with my probability modelling for a game.

What I have been trying to work out is how to check if a dice rolling situation progresses the probability in a reasonably linear manner.

**(This paragraph is wrong but I'm keeping it because the answer is much easier to understand given my epic mistype)** The game calls for a CL (Challenge level) which is the number at or above when rolled that counts as a success and the DR (difficulty rating) which is the number of successes needed to "win". I am attempting to model this using six-sided dice (d=6) in various numbers (n).

*(**What I should have said:** The game calls for a CL (Challenge level)  which is the number of successes needed to "win" and the DR (difficulty rating) which is the number at or above when rolled that counts as a success. I am attempting to model this using six-sided dice (d=6) in various numbers (n).)*

So I have put this together in a spreadsheet. I figured the best way to work out p(win) was to work out p(fail) and take that from 1.

For CL=1 I used `=1-(((6-(7-DR))/6)^n)` which I have checked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344202/what-is-the-probability-of-rolling-at-least-one-6-in-12-rolls-of-a-dice) and I am fairly sure is right. For CL>1, I used `=1-(((6-(7-DR))/6)^(n+1-CL))` 
as that seemed right at the time given that I was working out the probability of not rolling enough at or above CL.

I calculated the probability for CL=1-5 and DR=2-6. The probability curve came out looking like this:

[image: p-curve for CL/DR]

This is nothing like I was expecting and I have started to doubt my maths.

I tried reordering the CL/DR pairs to sorted by probability but that did not seem to have any pattern to it (here is charted for 5d6).

[image]

Can either (a) help me understand what I did wrong or (b) help me see why the CL/DR pairs progress so I can come up with a pattern that makes sense in a tabletop setting. They seem to be jumping all over the place?

I am hoping you are going to take a look at my work, enjoy a good laugh at my maths, and then show me what I did wrong because this does not seem like a very useful system the game in question unless I am very wrong somewhere.

Comment: Hi, you'll see my answer below. One thing that is not clear to me: is there a fixed number of rolls in the game? Or is it that you have to have a string of succesful rolls without a failure? I have modelled the first situation, but perhaps you mean the second?

Comment: I've assumed you just roll a bunch of dice at once and that you only have a fixed number. I've calculated for n=3-7 but n=5 was what I chose to graph. (Game 2 in your answer). However, game 1 is just hugely interesting because I'm a bit of a geek.

Comment: Ok, so that sounds like example Game 2 in the below, where of a fixed number of dice, at least a set number must be successful.

Comment: Hopefully the plot I've added also helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I have put two answers as I wasn't sure from the context which you are interested in.

In the first one, to win the game you must achieve the challenge level on successive throws, without a failure. Where the number of throws required to win is the difficulty rating.

In the second answer, I assume there is some fixed number of throws allowed, and that to win the number that exceed the challenge level must be at least the difficulty rating: but they do not have too happen successively.

**Update: The original poster has clarified that Game 2 is the one of interest. Game 1 is left for posterity**

---

---

**Game 1.**
In your game you have two parameters:

A roll of the dice is considered successful if it is equal to $k$ or greater (this is the challenge level), with $1 \leq k \leq 6$. Clearly if $k=1$ then every role is a success.

To win the game, you must have $n$ successful rolls in a row. i.e. you must roll at least a value of $k$ on $n$ rolls of the dice, without any failures. Let $p_{k,n}$ denote the probability of winning the game.

Due to the independence of each roll, the probability of winning when the difficulty rating is $n$ is equal to the probability of winning $n$ games with a difficulty rating of $1$. i.e.

$$p_{n,k} = p_{1,k}^n.$$

Then the probability of winning $1$ game is the probability of a dice roll being greater than or equal to $k$, which is

$$p_{1,k} = \frac{7-k}{6}.$$

Hence

$$p_{n,k} = \left(\frac{7-k}{6}\right)^n.$$

---

---

**Game 2.**

In this game you have three parameters:

A roll of the dice is considered successful if it is equal to $k$ or greater (this is the challenge level), with $1 \leq k \leq 6$. Clearly if $k=1$ then every role is a success.

In a given round we allow a total of $N$ rolls, and we say that the game was won if at least $n$ of these rolls are succesful (i.e. exceed $k$). $n$ therefore denotes the `difficulty rating' in your notation.

As I understand, you are asking: Given $k,\, N,\,n$ what is the probability that the player wins the game?

As in the last game, the probability that a given roll is at least the challenge level $k$ is given by
$$p= \frac{7-k}{6}.$$

That is, the probability that a given roll is a success is distributed according to a $\text{Bernoulli}(p)$ distribution.

With this in mind, we now want to know the probability that in $N$ rolls, at least $n$ exceed $k$. We assume that each roll of the dice is independent, then this is the same as asking if a $\text{Binomial}(N,p)$ distribution is greater than or equal to $n$.

The above is a standard result in probability that relies on the fact that any given the number of successes of $N$ independent Bernoulli distributions is Binomially distributed.

Therefore the probability you are interested in is:

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}\big( \text{Bin}(N,p) \geq n \big) & =
\sum_{m = n}^N \binom{N}{m} p^m (1-p)^{N-m} \\
& = \sum_{m = n}^N \binom{N}{m} \left(\frac{7-k}{6}\right)^m \left(\frac{k-1}{6}\right)^{N-m}
\end{align*}
Unfortunately there is little more rearranging that is possible (save for pulling out the factors of $1/6$); this is known to be the case as there is no closed form expression for the partial sum of binomial coefficients.

In the below I plot the case where $N = 5$ dice are used, and we vary the challenge level ($x$-axis), and difficulty rating (different plot lines).
[image]

Comment: I find that plot fascinating. It looks like they spread out and then converge again.

Comment: I think the interpretation of that (if this makes any sense outside of my own head) is: when something is really easy to achieve once (eg. rolling at least a 1 on a dice is guaranteed) then its easy to do multiple times, hence why they're close at CL = 1. On the other end of the spectrum, if something is hard to do once (rolling at least a 6... or worse, rolling at least a 6 twice), then it is even harder to do it multiple times. So since it is extremely hard to role a 6 on 3 of 5 dice (i.e. already close to 0 probability), it'll also be close to 0 to role a 6 on 5 dice.

Comment: The only thing that is throwing me for turning your formula into spreadsheet formula is that for me CL is the target number of success and DR is the number we are shooting for. At least the probability curves look reasonable now. which is what matters to me. :)

Comment: Are you sure, I just re-read your description, and it says: a CL (Challenge level) which is the number at or above when rolled that counts as a success and the DR (difficulty rating) which is the number of successes needed to "win"." So this is the same definition that I used. So in the plot above, the blue curve is when you must achieve the challenge level on 4 out of 5 dice, i.e. number of successes required to win is 4.

Comment: One nice property you can see from the graph... The cases (CL,DF) equal to (3,4), (4,3), and (5,2) all have success probabilities roughly equal to 0.5... But psychologically a player might feel they have a better chance of rolling at least a 3 on 4 of the dice, than of rolling at least a 5 on two of them. With larger number of dice, you could find even closer matched pairs, so you could really play with this psychology, with very little change in the probability.

Comment: That could be me. I swap things about without realising when I am tired or stressed.

Comment: You are right. I talked utter nonsense and yet you still were able to answer the question. Props to you.

Comment: (+1) but there's a typo: in the equation, that should be ${\text{Bin}}(N,p)$, not ${\text{Ber}}(N,p)$.